# Cassandra connection exception

Tags: java, cassandra

I have this code:

```
private final String CONTACT_POINT = "127.0.0.1";
private SynchronizationTableManager()
{
     cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(CONTACT_POINT).build();;
     session = cluster.connect(KEYSPACE);
    createTableIfNotExists();
}
```

I get the following exception:

> All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect)) with stack trace: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))

This happens on the line calling `cluster.connect(KEYSPACE)`. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: telnet 127.0.0.1 9042 to check if server is running

Comment: Which version of Cassandra are you using?

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely a problem with **cassandra.yaml** settings. Please check the settings of **[listen_address](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__listen_address)**, **[rpc_address](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__rpc_address)**, and **[broadcast_rpc_address](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__broadcast_rpc_address)**.

Please also check the connection requirements for the Java driver: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/wiki/Connection-requirements

Also what does **nodetool ring** tell you about your C* node? Can you connect to your node over **cqlsh**?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same exception when i connect from my local machine to cassandra cluster using ssl certificate.
For my case, Java version giving some problem. I was using java 1.80_91 which is little bit older version. After that i updated my java version to 1.8.0_221. That is work for me.

This may helpful ,someone in the same boat.