# Can't connect to Cassandra (All host(s) tried for query failed

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I am trying to setup Datastax OpsCenter.

When I tried to run datastax-agent I get the following error:

```
Can't connect to Cassandra (All host(s) tried for query failed (tried:
/X.X.X.X1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException:
[/X.X.X.X1:9042] Cannot connect), /X.X.X.X2:9042 
(com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: 
[/X.X.X.X2:9042] Cannot connect), /X.X.X.X3:9042 
(com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: 
[/X.X.X.X3:9042] Cannot connect), /X.X.X.X4:9042, /X.X.X.X5:9042, 
/X.X.X.X6:9042 [only showing errors of first 3 hosts, use getErrors() 
for more details])), retrying soon.
```

Please let me know if any other details are required.

Comment: found the above error in /opscenter_agent/log/agent.log

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905595/cassandra-connection-exception and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35043183/cannot-connect-to-datastax-agent